# TypeScript type alias for key-value pair

Tags: typescript

I have an interface as:

```
export interface PostEventTypeMap {
  changePrice: number;
  changeQuantity: number;
  signalConnected: boolean;
  signalDisconnected: boolean;
}
```

how I can define a type alias like:

```
type PostEvent = {
  type: keyof PostEventTypeMap,
  value: **Value based on key value and PostEventTypeMap**
};
```

I can not make postEvent property generic:

```
PostBoxService {
  get postEvent(): Observable<PostEvent> {
    return getOrCreateValue(this, "postEvent", () => new BehaviorSubject(null));
  }
}
```

---

The usecase of service:

```
postBoxService
  .postEvent
  .subscribe(event => {
    if (!event)
      return;

    switch (event.type) {
      case "changePrice":
        this.changePrice(event.value);
        break;
      case "changeQuantity":
        this.changeQuantity(event.value);
        break;
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you have a finite number of possibilities, and since the `type` value will always be a literal type, you can make this a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions).  One way to do this is to [map](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) the `PostEventTypeMap` properties to the union members you want, and then immediately [look up](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) these properties to get a union:

```
type ObjToTypeValueUnion<T extends object> = 
  { [K in keyof T]-?: { type: K, value: T[K] } }[keyof T]

type PostEvent = ObjToTypeValueUnion<PostEventTypeMap>;
/* type PostEvent = {
    type: "changePrice";
    value: number;
} | {
    type: "changeQuantity";
    value: number;
} | {
    type: "signalConnected";
    value: boolean;
} | {
    type: "signalDisconnected";
    value: boolean;
} */
```

You can verify that this works as desired for your use case:

```
declare function changePrice(x: number): void;
declare function changeQuantity(x: number): void;
((event?: PostEvent) => {
  if (!event)
    return;

  switch (event.type) {
    case "changePrice":
      changePrice(event.value);
      break;
    case "changeQuantity":
      changeQuantity(event.value);
      break;
  }
});
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgAoHsDOYCiA3CcAFQE8AHCAWTjOQG8AoZZBACzhAHMJUpgkAXMhABXALYAjaAG4mLdlwgBFERzDAwJIaMky5mYJxBwANgGF0IEBASQAJkInp0JiB1nMDR0wBFgmBEtrWwgHZCcXNxBZAF8GBk0KZAB5CQArInRSCgA1UxEIAFUQYEsAHiJkCAAPSBA7TGR0dJswAD5kAF56ZABtAGlkUGQAawgSdBhkIgBdAFoAfiE6ZESIIX6AGmQ8fPXpgZnkGOPesYmp2fi1tCxcAnAulPTM7Ig8kwLi0pAyjGx8IQwG9qGQ2rIAPQAKlW5BQ-3uQKejGYzDWQgARGwONxePwIBiPKjdp99jopFBYsgAD70ORouGY7GKFRqDQkQnIek7PbacQUqm0lGo9HIDFeYzmIKtUKE7kkgqOZyudwME5C7mi8WGSV+ALSkJ2OWonmkpWRVUnKEQ+J2GwmOBQFAwEQgWw-eQ4nh8JAACmqfN0UAAlEI8OhgHZZHaEA6ncgXW71JZPSzVOB2f7AxTQzsI1GGL7fRAHmAlrcAaXg10OsLgFNfQBCEtA4Pcp1gERQaLxTwAdw0bGQxdLADo1tXhcwEHBMCgsQpcT6CQJudPF978SOgaOFRBg0STRInXARoeWLP58zuKyM5oMauTeuvbf1Jpt+Bd3sD2vwiez3IcQxAeQA)

Answer (score 1):

You may need to make the `PostEvent` type generic, as in:

```
export interface PostEventTypeMap {
  changePrice: number;
  changeQuantity: number;
  signalConnected: boolean;
  signalDisconnected: boolean;
}

type PostEvent<T extends keyof PostEventTypeMap> = {
  type: T,
  value: PostEventTypeMap[T]
};

const validChangePrice: PostEvent<'changePrice'> = {
  type: 'changePrice',
  value: 1
}

const invalidChangePrice: PostEvent<'changePrice'> = {
  type: 'changePrice',
  value: true // Compile error TS2322: Type 'true' is not assignable to type 'number'.
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I do not want to make it generic. because I use this type as return type of getter property