# Typing array[index] within a Reduce function, Property 'value' does not exist on type 'A| B| C|D'

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I've been diving deep into TypeScript recently and encountered a challenge while working with `Promise.allSettled`. My goal is to fetch various pieces of weather data concurrently (like hourly forecast, daily forecast, air pollution, UV index, and current weather conditions). After fetching, I'm processing these promises within a loop, specifically in a `reduce` function, to organize the data into a structured format.

```js
public async fetchAllData(): Promise<FetchResult> {
      try {
        const results = await Promise.allSettled([
          this.getHourlyForecast(23),
          this.getDailyForecast(10),
          this.getAirPollution(),
          this.getUvIndexForecast,
          this.getCurrentWeather
        ]);
        const promiseNames:(keyof AccType)[] = [
          'hourlyData', 
          'tenDayForecast', 
          'airPollution', 
          'uvIndex', 
          'currentWeather'
        ];
        const data = promiseNames.reduce((
          acc: AccType, 
          name: keyof AccType, 
          index: number) => {
          if (results[index].status === 'fulfilled') {
            acc[name] = (results[index]).value   // error is here
          } else {
            acc[name] = undefined;
          }
          return acc;
        }, {});
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data.airPollution, null, 2));
        return data;
      } catch (error: any) {
        return { error: error.message };
      }
    }
```

​ here is the error :

> [{ "resource": "/C:/Users/Shiha/Desktop/resume/app/(weather)/class.tsx", "owner": "typescript", "code": "2339", "severity": 8, "message": "Property 'value' does not exist on type 'PromiseRejectedResult | PromiseFulfilledResult | PromiseFulfilledResult | PromiseFulfilledResult<...> | PromiseFulfilledResult<...> | PromiseFulfilledResult<...>'.\n Property 'value' does not exist on type 'PromiseRejectedResult'.", "source": "ts", "startLineNumber": 95, "startColumn": 42, "endLineNumber": 95, "endColumn": 47 }]

The crux of my issue lies in typing the results of `Promise.allSettled` within the `reduce` function. As you can see, I'm currently using `(results[index] as PromiseFulfilledResult<any>).value` to extract the value of fulfilled promises, but this uses `any`, which I'm trying to avoid to leverage TypeScript's type safety features fully.

I'm looking for 2 things:

- A way to dynamically assign types to the results based on the promise it corresponds to, thus avoiding the use of `any`.
- How to handle this within a loop, especially using the `reduce` function, in a way that TypeScript can understand and enforce the types of each result correctly.

I've met this problem so many times, but every time I just use `any` to skip it. I'm looking for a better way to handle this.

Comment: There's nothing much better, I'm afraid, see [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58981956/how-can-i-move-away-from-a-partialt-to-t-without-casting-in-typescript).  Does that fully address your question or am I missing something?

Comment: What is the ultimate goal here? Do you want to have a result with all promises resolved and mapped to your output object? Or do you want a result which only has the values of resolved promises?

Comment: The below answer from @Shane fully solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 solutions to your issue.

1. is elegant and uses some advanced typescript features.
2. is more bare bones and readable

**First, some code shared by both solutions:**

```
type AccType = {
    uvIndex: number | undefined
    currentWeather: string | undefined
}

function getUvIndexForecast(): Promise<number> {
    return Promise.resolve(123)
}

function getCurrentWeather(): Promise<string> {
    return Promise.resolve("weather")
}
```

**Solution 1**

```
type KeyValuePair<T> = { 
    [K in keyof T]-?: { key: K, value: T[K] } 
}[keyof T]

async function fetchAllData(): Promise<AccType> {
    const req: Promise<KeyValuePair<AccType>>[] = [
        getUvIndexForecast().then(value => ({key: "uvIndex", value})),
        getCurrentWeather().then(value => ({key: "currentWeather", value}))
    ]

    const response = await Promise.allSettled(req)
    return response
        .reduce((s, x) => x.status === "fulfilled"
            ? { ...s, [x.value.key]: x.value.value } 
            : s, {} as AccType)
}
```

inspired by: [TypeScript type alias for key-value pair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64444404/typescript-type-alias-for-key-value-pair)

**Solution 2**

```
function rejectedAsUndefined<T>(promise: Promise<T>): Promise<T | undefined> {
    return promise.catch(_ => undefined)
}

async function fetchAllData(): Promise<AccType> {
    const uvIndex = rejectedAsUndefined(getUvIndexForecast())
    const currentWeather = rejectedAsUndefined(getCurrentWeather())

    return {
        uvIndex: await uvIndex,
        currentWeather: await currentWeather
    }
}
```

Comment: both solution all work, you are amazing bro.  use "[keyof T]" as union type and "-?" explicitly declare the type are amazing